# Is it with Curses possible, to print to STDERR instead of STDOUT?

Tags: perl, stderr, curses

How could I print "Hello, World!\n" (using [Curses](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Curses)) to `STDERR` instead of `STDOUT`?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.12.0;
use Curses;

initscr();

addstr( 10, 0, "Hello, World!\n" );
refresh();

sleep 3;
endwin();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having never used curses, but presuming it would be an argument to `initscr`, I did `man initscr`, which gave:

> A program that outputs to more than one terminal should use the `newterm` routine for each terminal instead of `initscr`. [...]

So you get something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Curses;

open(my $stderr_term_in, '<', '/dev/null') or die $!;

my $stdout_scr = newterm($ENV{TERM}, \*STDOUT, \*STDIN);
my $stderr_scr = newterm($ENV{TERM}, \*STDERR, $stderr_term_in);

set_term($stdout_scr);
addstr(10, 0, "Hello, STDOUT!\n");
refresh();

set_term($stderr_scr);
addstr(10, 0, "Hello, STDERR!\n");
refresh();

set_term($stdout_scr);
endwin();
delscreen($stdout_scr);

set_term($stderr_scr);
endwin();
delscreen($stderr_scr);
```